# Intercomponent Communication

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-1.6

I work with Angular 1.6.
I have component "user-details", which contains two other components "switcher" and "user-table"like this:

```
<user-details>
    <switcher> </switcher>
    <user-table> </user-table>
</user-details>
```

"switcher" component contains md-switcher and "user-table" contains table with data. I need hiding my "user-table" components with the help of ng-if directive, when I press on md-switcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `<user-table>` component with a `div` (or even `span`) and then use the `ng-if` or `ng-show`. The condition for hiding this component can then be changed with `md-switcher`.

So assuming you have a md-switcher like this:

```
<md-switch ng-model="canShow" aria-label="Show?">
  Show ?
</md-switch>
```

The expression `"canShow"` is used to bind the data and is later used to decide to show/hide the `<user-table>` like this:

```
<div ng-show="canShow" ...>
  <user-table> </user-table>
</div>
```

Although I used `div`, I am sure you can get similar effect using `span`. Give it a try and let us know if it helps.

Comment: In what way? Are you getting errors or are you expecting a different approach?

Comment: When I add ng-if to div which is wrap for component user-details, it is hiding always - when I click on md-switch in true position or when I click md-switch in false position.
Why did this happen? :(

Comment: Please try doing the same using `ng-show` as in the example that I provided - if this does not work, then we can look at it more closely, but I do think `ng-show` will work. I am not sure if this might have something to do with the fact that the `ng-if` directive **removes the HTML element** if the expression evaluates to false.